# Pre increment operator

Tags: pre-increment

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i=2;
    cout<<++i<<" "<<++i;
    return 0;
}
```

Why the output of program is '4 4' not '3 4' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because both increments occur before the line is output. the actual writing to the screen is delayed until the entire line has been run, but by then the reference for i has already had its value updated.

if you split your cout line into two discrete outputs, things would evaluate as you expect.

Comment: Does output also depends on the compiler one is using ?

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure, but cout is a stream, and a streams get built and then flushed as a whole, so my guess is that this behavior is inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

You have two side effects on the same variable (the two increments) with no sequence point between them.  So they might happen in any order or might even get interleaved -- the behavior is undefined.  You appear to be getting interleaved behaviors here -- the expression `++i` is increment I then read i.  So you're getting increment, increment, read, read.